# Is having a copy of SQL data in an application a good idea to save SQL SELECTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, architecture

I am working on a multithreading .NET 4 application which acquires data continuously and writes them into a SQL database (MySQL or SQL Server - not yet sure).

Everytime when a `INSERT` is executed, at leat one prior `SELECT` is necessary in order so synchronize with the databaes. This means the applications gets a block which contains new and old data and then has to check which data sets are new and which are already in the database.

This means a lot of `SELECTS` which result everytime in more or less the same data.

Would it be a good idea to have a copy of the last x entries per table within the application?
This way the synchronization could be done on the copy instead of the database.

Pro:

- Faster

Contra:

- Uses a lot of memory
- Risk of becomming unsynchronized with the database

What do you think? What is the best practice for such a use case?
Any other pros and cons?

Comment: Did you ever hear of the MERGE statement? A Merge instead of a Select/Insert par may be faster.

Comment: Unfortunately merging is out of question for me. If all data sets of a received data block are new, I have to request another older block until I am synchronized with the database. It's not nice but there is nothing I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an external program writing to your database at the same time, you can use buffering.

But instead of buffering SELECT results, just add to the insert method a buffer of the last X (a reasonable number) insertion requests, and only insert the new one if it isn't on that list.

You might also want to lock the insertion method, to make sure the inclusion check is always correct.

Comment: Thanks! Synchronizing on the INSERTS is a good idea. I will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple processes writing to the database, it is non-trivial to maintain perfect synchronization between in-memory data and the database. In fact the only way to confirm you are synchronized is by making a SELECT query on database. So you have a trade-off between perfect synchronization and synchronization with some tolerance which is very efficient.

My suggestions, which may help in both cases, would be:

1. Tune your SELECT queries. Add indexes if necessary.
2. Create meta-data, like version numbers. So that you have to only check something very trivial to determine if you need synchronization.
3. Write a stored proc which implements your SELECT and INSERT logic. Then you do not have to worry about making multiple calls to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Since I'm not planning to have multiple processes writing the same data to the database, I will try to have a in-memory copy.